# Can't Login System Preference After Changed Username

Tags: macos, password, login, preferences, administrator

**I just changed my username and after that I can't login in my System Preference**. Usually there will be my username and just fill the password but now all is blank. I used my new and old username to login but still can't login.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the version of macOS you are using to your original question.

Comment: if you tried your new username what did you use for a password?